# Not able to migrate data to mongodb from csv file include unix timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, data-migration, mongoimport

**csv sample**

timestamp,name,amount 
1571967208,Rahul,15.7 
1571967200,Raju,25.7

**code sample**

```
mongoimport --db=crypto --collection=t --type=csv \
   --columnsHaveTypes \
   --fields="timestamp.date(), name.string(), amount.double()" \
   --file="text.csv"
```

**result**

```
Failed: type coercion failure in document #1 for column 'timestamp', could not parse token '1571967208' to type date
```

Comment: Maybe try `timestamp.date(1136239445)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pre-process your CSV into [MongoDB Extended JSON (v2)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) using `jq` with something like:

```
jq --null-input --raw-input 'input | split(",") as $fields | inputs | split(",") as $values |{($fields[0]): {"$date": {"$numberLong": ($values[0]+"000")}}, ($fields[1]): $values[1], ($fields[2]): ($values[2] | tonumber)}' yourFile.csv > yourFile.json
```

This would transform your example CSV into:

```json
{
  "timestamp": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1571967208000"
    }
  },
  "name": "Rahul",
  "amount": 15.7
}
{
  "timestamp": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1571967200000"
    }
  },
  "name": "Raju",
  "amount": 25.7
}
```

See [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/RcCt5PIrJQI).

and then:

```
mongoimport --db=crypto --collection=t --file=yourFile.json
```